# How do I display gradually an string(visibility) from beginning to end?

Tags: java, android, visibility, arrays

I am new t android development and are having some issues with a Hang-Man game.

This is how i Want it to work: 
1. when the app starts the db is opened (db.open()) and a randomed word is fetched from the db (db.random()) and put in generatedWord String. The generatedWord is then made into the Spannablestring text (SpannableString text = new SpannableString(generatedWord);) and the whole text is made into color white/invisible.

1. when a user enters a char into the textview userInput I want to save it to lastInput vairable by using onKeyListener:
   lastInput = (char)event.getUnicodeChar();
2. and then when Enter button is hit the guess() should be called which sends lastInput s an argument. there it checks if lastInput is in indexOf generatedWord and if it is it will make the text of the chars black and visible again and if not it should call showImages() which in turn makes images visible.

THING IS! The db is working, I just got the app going with the gui and everything, then I made some small change and now I cant launch the app again and only get FATAL ERRORS. What have I done wrong and what can i think about?

Many thanks

// MAINACTIVITY

```
    package com.emanuelolsson.simplehangman;

import database.DBAdapter;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class HangMan extends Activity {

    // DECLARE NEEDED VARIABLES
    private String generatedWord = "";
    private char lastInput = '\0';  
    private Button newGameButton, enterLetterButton;
    private EditText wordHolder, userInput;
    private ImageView imageOne, imageTwo, imageThree, imageFour, imageFive, imageSix, imageSeven, imageEight, winner, hanged;
    private SpannableString text = new SpannableString(generatedWord);
    private int count = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hang_man);
        DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

        // ASSIGN OBJECTS
        newGameButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newGame);
        enterLetterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enter);
        wordHolder = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.wordHolder);
        userInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userInput);
        imageOne = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageTwo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        imageThree = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        imageFour = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        imageFive = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        imageSix = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
        imageSeven = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
        imageEight = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
        winner = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.winner);
        hanged = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.hanged);
        imageOne.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageTwo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageThree.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageFour.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageFive.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageSix.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageSeven.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageEight.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        winner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        hanged.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


        // ADD LISTENERS
        newGameButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

            }
        });

        enterLetterButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                guess(lastInput);
            }
        });

        userInput.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                lastInput = (char)event.getUnicodeChar();
                return false;
            }
        });

        db.open();
        db.randomize(generatedWord);
                SpannableString text = new SpannableString(generatedWord);
        text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), 0, text.length(), 0);  
        wordHolder.setText(text);
        db.close();
    }


// What happens when user clicks Enter
    // If the guess (char) is in the index of generated word and not -1 it will span back hopefully to all char
    public void guess(char guess) {
        guess = Character.toUpperCase(guess);
        if (generatedWord.indexOf(lastInput) != -1) {
            text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), text.charAt(lastInput), text.charAt(lastInput), 0);
            //guessedChars.add(guess);   
        } else {
            showImages();
        }
    }

    private void showImages() {

        count ++;

        if (count == 1) 
        {
            imageOne.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else if (count == 2)
        {
            imageTwo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else if (count == 3) 
        {
            imageThree.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else if (count == 4)
        {
            imageFour.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else if (count == 5) 
        {
            imageFive.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else if (count == 6)
        {
            imageSix.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else if (count == 7) 
        {
            imageSeven.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else if (count == 8)
        {
            gameEnd();
        }

    }

    private void gameEnd() {
        if (count == 8)
        {
            hanged.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
            winner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_hang_man, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

// DBAdapter

```
    package database;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBAdapter 
{
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_WORDS = "words";  
    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbnames";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "tblnames";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table tblnames (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "words text not null);";

    private final Context context; 

    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) 
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
        {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
        int newVersion) 
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion 
                    + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tblnames");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }    

    // Open DB
    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    // Close DB  
    public void close() 
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    // INsert name
    public long insertWord(String word) 
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_WORDS, word);
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    // Delete a name
    public boolean deleteWord(long rowId) 
    {
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + 
                "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    // Get all names
    public Cursor getAllWords() 
    {
        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID, 
                KEY_WORDS}, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null);
    }


    // Get a certain name
    public Cursor getWord(long rowId) throws SQLException 
    {
        Cursor mCursor =
                db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                        KEY_ROWID,
                        KEY_WORDS}, 
                        KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, 
                        null,
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    // Update name
    public boolean updateWord(long rowId, String word) 
    {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_WORDS, word);

        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, 
                         KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    // Clears DB
    public void clear() {

        db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, "1", null);

    }

    public void randomize(String word) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Cursor cursor;
        cursor =  this.db.query("tblnames ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", new String[] { "*" }, null, null, null, null, null);
    }
}
```

// LAYOUT

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:src="@drawable/one"
        android:contentDescription="@string/picOne" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:src="@drawable/two" 
        android:contentDescription="@string/picTwo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/picThree"
        android:src="@drawable/three" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:src="@drawable/four" 
        android:contentDescription="@string/picFour" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:src="@drawable/five"
        android:contentDescription="@string/picFive" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:src="@drawable/six"
        android:contentDescription="@string/picSix" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:src="@drawable/seven"
        android:contentDescription="@string/picSeven" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:src="@drawable/eight"
        android:contentDescription="@string/picEight" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/wordHolder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/enter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/wordHolder"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="@string/enter" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userInput"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/enter"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/wordHolder"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/enter"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/enter"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/winner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/winner"
        android:contentDescription="@string/winner" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/hanged"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/hanged"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hanged" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/newGame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/enter"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/enter"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/enter"
        android:text="@string/newGame" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION: check guess for the showing of correct letter-guesses again from _ to appropriate letter.

// MainActivity.java

```
    package com.emanuelolsson.simplehangman;

import database.DBAdapter;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HangMan extends Activity {

    // DECLARE NEEDED VARIABLES  
    private Button newGameButton, enterLetterButton;
    private EditText userInput;
    private TextView wordHolder;
    private ImageView imageOne, imageTwo, imageThree, imageFour, imageFive, imageSix, imageSeven, imageEight, winner, hanged;
    private String hiddenWord, randomedWord;
    private int count = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hang_man);
        DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

        // ASSIGN OBJECTS
        newGameButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newGame);
        enterLetterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enter);
        wordHolder = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wordHolder);
        userInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userInput);
        imageOne = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageTwo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        imageThree = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        imageFour = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        imageFive = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        imageSix = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
        imageSeven = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
        imageEight = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
        winner = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.winner);
        hanged = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.hanged);
        imageOne.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageTwo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageThree.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageFour.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageFive.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageSix.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageSeven.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageEight.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        winner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        hanged.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        wordHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        // ADD LISTENERS
        newGameButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                newGame();

            }
        });

        enterLetterButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if (!(userInput.getText().toString().isEmpty()) )
                {
                    guess();
                } else if (userInput.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You need to insert a letter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }
        });
        db.open();
        db.fill();
        randomedWord = db.randomize();
        invWord();
        wordHolder.setText(hiddenWord);
        db.clear();
        db.close();
    }

    public void newGame() {
        DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
        count = 0;
        imageOne.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageTwo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageThree.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageFour.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageFive.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageSix.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageSeven.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageEight.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        winner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        hanged.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        db.open();
        db.fill();
        randomedWord = db.randomize();
        invWord();
        wordHolder.setText(hiddenWord);
        db.clear();
        db.close();
    }

    public void invWord() 
    {
        hiddenWord = randomedWord;
        hiddenWord = hiddenWord.replaceAll(".", "_" +" ");
    }

    public void guess()
    {
        char guess = userInput.getText().charAt(0);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(hiddenWord);
        String j = ""+guess;
        int index = randomedWord.indexOf(guess);

        if (randomedWord.contains(j))
        {
            while (index >= 0) 
            {
                builder.setCharAt(index*2, guess);
                index = randomedWord.indexOf(guess, index + 1);
                hiddenWord = builder.toString().trim();
                wordHolder.setText(hiddenWord);
                if (!(hiddenWord.toString().contains("_".toString())) )
                {
                    winner();
                }
            }   
        }
        else 
        {
            showImages();
        }
    }

    private void winner()
    {
        imageOne.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageTwo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageThree.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageFour.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageFive.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageSix.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageSeven.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageEight.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        winner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    private void showImages() {

        count ++;

        if (count == 1) 
        {
            imageOne.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else if (count == 2)
        {
            imageTwo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else if (count == 3) 
        {
            imageThree.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else if (count == 4)
        {
            imageFour.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else if (count == 5) 
        {
            imageFive.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else if (count == 6)
        {
            imageSix.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else if (count == 7) 
        {
            imageSeven.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else if (count == 8)
        {   
            gameEnd();
        }

    }

    private void gameEnd() 
    {

        imageOne.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageTwo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageThree.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageFour.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageFive.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageSix.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageSeven.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageEight.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        hanged.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        wordHolder.setText(randomedWord);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_hang_man, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

// XML

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/picOne"
        android:src="@drawable/one" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/picTwo"
        android:src="@drawable/two" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/picThree"
        android:src="@drawable/three" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/picFour"
        android:src="@drawable/four" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/picFive"
        android:src="@drawable/five" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/picSix"
        android:src="@drawable/six" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/picSeven"
        android:src="@drawable/seven" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/picEight"
        android:src="@drawable/eight" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/winner"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/winner"
        android:src="@drawable/winner" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/hanged"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hanged"
        android:src="@drawable/hanged" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wordHolder"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="134dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/newGame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/wordHolder"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/newGame" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/enter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/newGame"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/newGame"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/newGame"
        android:text="@string/enter" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userInput"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/enter"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/enter"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/enter"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textSize="20dp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@+id/header"
        android:src="@drawable/header" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not doing it this way?

```
String wordToGuess = "ANDROID";
Set<Character> guessedChars = new HashSet<Character>();

// call this with the user-input
//
public void guess(char guess) {
    guess = Character.toUpperCase(guess);
    if (wordToGuess.indexOf(guess) != -1) {
        guessedChars.add(guess);
    }
}

// call this afterwards to get string with chars guessed so far and dots for not-yet-guessed characters
//
public String guessedSoFar() {
    String result = "";
    for (char ch: wordToGuess.toCharArray()) {
        if (guessedChars.contains(ch)) {
            result += ch;
        } else {
            result += ".";   // . for not yet guessed words
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```